# Crystal Reports 13.0.x Dynamic Picklist is not populated in web viewer with 64 bit engine

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

We are using Crystal Reports and have a report with a dynamic picklist. If I load it under a 32 bit process, I get the picklist properly populated. If I instead run it under a 64 bit process, I instead get an empty picklist and a textbox where the user can type in whatever they feel like and add it to the selection. I have a discussion on the SAP support site at http://scn.sap.com/thread/3342435, but so far it has not yielded any solution. My demonstration project loads the report like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = 
    Server.MapPath("~/DynamicPickListNew.rpt");
}
```

It's using the report's saved connection, but even manually setting the connection yields the same result. This demonstration report has 2 dynamic picklists, 1 static picklist and one query for the content of the report. The output shows:

- 2 picklists (dynamic) with values under a 32 bit app pool, empty on 64 bit app pool
- 1 picklist (static) with values under both app pools
- data rows from the database under both app pools.

I think this report sufficiently demonstrates that:

1. CR is able to connect to the database and retrieve data as evidenced by the data rows
2. has a bug in the 64 bit engine that prevents the dynamic picklists from working as evidenced by the lack of values in those lists when running in a 64 bit app pool.

Has anybody encountered this bug? Did you find a solution? We cannot use the 32 bit engine because that has it's own issues (specifically it crashes under heavy load, where 'heavy' is defined as a single user attempting to click through a few pages of the report or searching or zooming).

Thanks.

UPDATE: further testing has demonstrated that this problem exists when the rpt file contains a command object. The command doesn't need to be used by the dynamic picklist (or indeed used at all), just be present in the file.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this behavior is a bug in CR. See http://scn.sap.com/message/14118328#14118328.